# Does Raspberry Pi 4 support Android Things?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I've been using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Android things but in this there is RAM issue so I want to switch it to the Raspberry Pi 4. Does anyone know about this?

Comment: question for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: No. All supported hardware platforms described [here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware).

Answer (score 4):

No, Android Things is only supported on the Raspberry Pi 3B in the RPi family. The 4 is not supported.

Comment: Does Dev Board from Google and Banana Pi support Android things?

Comment: I'm not sure what "Dev Board from Google" you're referring to. The Banana Pi definitely doesn't support it. See [this list](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware) for the complete set of supported development boards.